# Convert CFString to NSString - Swift

Tags: string, swift, serial-port, iokit

I'm trying to write a program that will scan for available serial ports and present them in a popup menu. Why can I not take the `CFString` straight from the `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty()` function and add it to the menu via string interpolation in the next line? For some reason my variable declaration is met with the error:

> "NSString is not a subtype of CFString".

```
import Foundation

import Cocoa

import IOKit
import IOKit.serial


@objc class Serial {

    init() {
    }

    @IBOutlet var serialListPullDown : NSPopUpButton!

    func refreshSerialList(defaultprompt: String) {


        let masterPort: mach_port_t = kIOMasterPortDefault
        let classesToMatch: CFDictionary =     IOServiceMatching(kIOSerialBSDServiceValue).takeUnretainedValue()
        var matchingServices: io_iterator_t = 0

        // remove everything from the pull down list
        serialListPullDown?.removeAllItems()

        // ask for all the serial ports
        let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, classesToMatch, &matchingServices)
        if kernResult == KERN_SUCCESS {
            // success
            while (io_object_t() == IOIteratorNext(matchingServices)) {
                var serialport = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(io_object_t(), kIOCalloutDeviceKey, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)

                serialListPullDown?.addItemWithTitle("\(serialport)")
            }
        }
        else {
            // error
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Swift.String and NSString are toll free bridged.

NSString and CFString can be cast to one another, but you can't directly cast from a Swift String to a CFString or vice versa.

Follow these steps to cast from a Core Foundation String to a Swift String:

```
var cfStr:CFString = "Soon, I'll be a Swift String"
var nsTypeString = cfStr as NSString
var swiftString:String = nsTypeString
```

Example for CFTypeRef:

```
var cfStr:CFTypeRef = "Soon, I'll be a Swift String"
var nsTypeString = cfStr as NSString
var swiftString:String = nsTypeString
```

Comment: So that would become this? http://imgur.com/ecm3JHM Because it's returning the same error for me.

Comment: IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty returns a CFTypeRef, so you need to declare your var type CFTypeRef not CFString

Comment: @user3185748 CFTypeRef is like Any for Core Foundation

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your patience as I try to wrap my head around this. The suggested CFTypeRef however doesn't appear to fix the issue: http://imgur.com/DxKrGiX

Comment: @user3185748 no problem, OK next lets look at what you are calling IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty with. What type is kIOCalloutDeviceKey? I think it needs to be a CFString, cast it like this: CFSTR(kIOCalloutDeviceKey)

Comment: That seems a little closer, now it's just giving me: "Use of unresolved identifier 'CFSTR'".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59475/discussion-between-john-woods-and-user3185748).

Comment: Perhaps recent changes to Swift changed the behavior: It seems that at least as of Swift version 2.0 you can now convert directly from `CFString`: `var swiftString:String = cfStr as String`.
Your `var swiftString:String = nsTypeString` example now needs suffix `as String` in order to compile.

Comment: How to do it on systems where they aren't bridged (like ­– any !APPLE system)?

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer NSString isn't available outside Apple platforms.

Comment: @Woodstock No, `NSString` is available on Linux -- same as `Foundation`, just the automatic bridging is not present due to the lack of an Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 17):

**At least as of Swift 2.0** (verify from a terminal with `swift --version`), you can **convert a `CFString` to a native Swift `String` with a simple `as String`**.

This is sufficient, since Swift's `String` type can be used anywhere `NSString` is expected.

An **example** with a `kUTType*` constant (`kUTType*` constants are defined by CoreServices and are `CFString`s):

```
// Get UTF8 plain text from the pasteboard.
import AppKit
let str = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard().stringForType(kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String)
```

A **more detailed example**:

```
// Import at least the Foundation framework.
// Since Cocoa includes Foundation, `import Cocoa` works too.
// (Note that `import CoreServices`, even though it defines type `CFString`,
// is NOT enough - the conversion will fail.)
import Foundation

// Create a CFString.
// The fact that initializing from a `String` literal here works implies that
// the *reverse* cast - String -> CFString - also works.
var cfStr:CFString = "Cast me."

// Convert it to String.
var swiftStr = cfStr as String
```

---

To **test what type** you're dealing with:

```
cfStr is CFString // true
swiftStr is String // true
```

To **get the string's type**, use `.dynamicType`; in a string context, this reports the **type name** but note that you may get the name of a  *private internal* class back:

```
"cfStr is a \(cfStr.dynamicType) instance."
// -> "cfStr is a _NSContiguousString instance." !!
```

Still, you can treat this as a `CFString`, as the `is` test above shows.

Use `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName()` to get **the true, underlying class name**:

```
_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(cfStr) // -> "ObjectC.CFString"
_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(kUTTypeUTF8PlainText) // ditto
```

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I like to make extentions and use them afterwards.
It seems convenient and clear to read:

Extention:

```
extension CFString {
    var string: String {
        return self as String
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let specificQueryPart: [String: NSObject] = [
            kSecReturnData.string: true as NSObject,
            kSecAttrService.string: key as NSObject,
            kSecMatchLimit.string: kSecMatchLimitOne
        ]
```