# How to extract name from a contact in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, addressbookui

I have picked up a contact from the address book

Now I need to display the name to the text view UI in the same view controller.

How to extract the name from the ABRecord?

This is my code.

```
@IBAction func addContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    var peoplePicker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
    self.presentViewController(peoplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {

    var name : String! = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person)
}
```

Here the function ABRecordCopyCompositeName return unmanaged I can't force cast to String. It says not convertible.

I'm new to iOS dev. please help.

Comment: You need to convert the CFString to String. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351842/convert-cfstring-to-nsstring-swift

Comment: the API is deprecated. Use the CNContact framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use takeUnretainedValue() and takeRetainedValue() to get CFString object and cast it to NSString

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {
    let nameCFString : CFString = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue()
    let name : NSString = nameCFString as NSString
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also check [KBContactsSelection](http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/kbcontactsselection-ios-address-book-ui-library/) which allows you to search and select multiple contacts and is easily customizable using elegant [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

[image: KBContactsSelection screen]