# CFString! is not convertible to String in swift 1.2

Tags: iphone, swift

There is this function in Alamofire

```
func escape(string: String) -> String {
    let legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped: CFStringRef = ":/?&=;+!@#$()',*"

    return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, string, nil, legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue)

}
```

Complier show "CFString! is not convertible to String" error in this func. I have tried [Convert CFString to NSString - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351842/convert-cfstring-to-nsstring-swift) to cast this , but have no luck.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Xcode 6.3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_23):

> The implicit conversions from bridged Objective-C classes (NSString/NSArray/NSDictionary) to their corresponding Swift value types (String/Array/Dictionary) have been removed, making the Swift type system simpler and more predictable.
>   ...
>   In order to perform such a bridging conversion, make the conversion explicit with the `as` keyword.

You have to convert `CFString/NSString` to a Swift `String` explicitly:

```
func escape(string: String) -> String {
    let legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped: CFStringRef = ":/?&=;+!@#$()',*"

    return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, string,
        nil, legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped,
        CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue) as String
                                     // HERE ---^
}
```

The conversion in the other direction (Swift `String` to `NSString`) is still done automatically, that's why the the `string` parameter of your
function can be passed directly  to the
`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` function which expects
a `CFString` argument.